# how can I handle internationalization with shieldui

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, shieldui

I'm using shieldui components and I would like to switch within the web app to another language.
How can I handle this **internationalization** with **shieldui**? 
I hope that translation of every minified js-file is **not** the only way to do so ...

Answer (score 0):

Internationalization is handled by using the Globalize JS package, as shown in [this calendar demo](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/calendar/localization).

Another example how you can run it is located [here](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/asp.net.chart/localization).

If there are strings that are hard-coded in the minified JS files, you should contact Shield UI's support for assistance with that.